# Can anyone explain the sentence structure for prepositions and using adjectives/numbers and measure words?

Tags: grammar, mandarin

It's hard to remember where 有，在 and prepositions go. I'm also not sure how I would add adjectives to do with colour/size/numbers would go in the sentence.

Comment: I recommend checking out Allset Learning's Chinese Grammar Wiki: https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/A2_grammar_points
You may find the A1 and B1 pages also useful for your questions.

Comment: That's an awesome link. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: That's amazing! Incredibly helpful with lots of info on everything, thank you so much!

Comment: You can roughly tell the difference. "有" stands for existence, but emphasizes possession. "在" also means existence, but the emphasis is on being.